# Why place a connective in between a subject and an auxiliary verb?

Tags: difference, usage, subject-verb-agreement

[image: Source]

> Sometimes it is the people that(or who) nobody imagines anything of, who do the things that(or which) no one can imagine.

I question why should we place **who** in the above sentence. For example:

> The boy who is studious who scores good. - **Incorrect**
>
> The boy who is studious scores good. - **Correct**

I am implying that the subject and the auxiliary verb should be directly connected and why should we place a connective like **who** in between them.

Comment: Because of **it is**. Without "it is":   Sometimes people that no one imagines anything of do the things no one can imagine.

Comment: First, the comma between "of" and "who" is an error. The subject is "it", the verb "is", and the remainder of the sentence a noun phrase functioning as a PC (predicative complement). The noun phrase PC  consists of "people" as head with two embedded relative clauses: "That no one imagines anything of" and "who do things no one can imagine".

Comment: @BillJ **First, the comma between "of" and "who" is an error.** Why should you say that?

Comment: The relative clause is of the integrated (defining) kind that should not be set off with a comma. Here is the original quote [link](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/87041.Alan_Turing)